# How to automatically get the exception type and message from C++ programs on Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, exception, terminal

From Linux I know that in case a C++ program throws an exception, the exception type and message are printed on the terminal while the program dies. On mac, however, the only thing you get is:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
Abort trap: 6
```

Of course I could run the program in a debugger, but that's usually much more overhead just to see the exception type and message.

Is there any way to enable exception type and message printing on mac with any magic command?

Edit: I know what the correct way is to handle such situations with exception handling. It is more out of curiosity to find out whether the linux behavior can be reproduced on mac.

Comment: if you want exactly that behavior then I guess you would have to exec the program yourself from a little helper, and catch the exception (not 100% sure that would work) or register your own signal handler and print something as you crash.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to guarantee the information of a *C++ exception* is printed to the console you can add a try/catch block in `main()` like below.

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try { return mymain(argc, argv); }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Unhandled exception thrown: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know of course. I just want to know whether there is a way to emulate the Linux behavior on mac.

Comment: The Windows command line has this same problem!  I don't yet know how to solve it other than using this answer.